# How to create a variable with a character chain present in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have this data.frame

```
c=c("AUSTOP","ATIP;AITUO", "BERTUI", "BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU", "FRTEU3", "IRTUFH","HAZEB", "ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE", "DAIER1", "ZERV")

pos=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
data=data.frame(pos, c, xab)

> data
   pos                     c
1    1                AUSTOP
2    2            ATIP;AITUO
3    3                BERTUI
4    4 BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU
5    5                FRTEU3
6    6                IRTUFH
7    7                 HAZEB
8    8  ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE
9    9                DAIER1
10  10                  ZERV
```

And this vector :

```
xa=c("AUSTOP", "HTURIE", "IRTUFH", "JEURTU", "AITUO", "ERTUJG", "HERTYE", "DAIER", "ZERV1")
```

I would like to create another variable with for each line all the character chain present both in the c variable and in the xa vector as follows:

```
> data2
   pos                     c           xab
1    1                AUSTOP        AUSTOP
2    2            ATIP;AITUO         AITUO
3    3                BERTUI        BERTUI
4    4 BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU          <NA>
5    5                FRTEU3          <NA>
6    6                IRTUFH        IRTUFH
7    7                 HAZEB          <NA>
8    8  ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE ERTUJG;HERTYE
9    9                DAIER1          <NA>
10  10                  ZERV          <NA>
```

If there is a solution in tidyverse, it would be great.

Comment: In your `xa` vector there is no 'BERTUI'

Comment: @Patrick. Tip - don't use ``c`` as a variable name - because ``c`` is also used as a function, you could end up doing something unintended with that variable name

Comment: Thank you for these notices. I agree this is not a good idea to use c as a variable name. I am not used to it usually, it was just for the example but I will try to avoid it even for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a single pattern by `paste`ing the 'xa' together with `collapse` as `|`, use `str_extract_all` to get all the strings that match the pattern from the 'c' column, loop over the `list` and `paste` them

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
    mutate(new = map_chr(str_extract_all(c, str_c("\\b(", str_c(xa,
        collapse="|"), ")\\b")), str_c, collapse=";"))
```

-output

```
  pos                     c           new
1    1                AUSTOP        AUSTOP
2    2            ATIP;AITUO         AITUO
3    3                BERTUI        BERTUI
4    4 BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU              
5    5                FRTEU3              
6    6                IRTUFH        IRTUFH
7    7                 HAZEB              
8    8  ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE ERTUJG;HERTYE
9    9                DAIER1              
10  10                  ZERV
```

#### data

```
xa <- c("AUSTOP", "HTURIE", "IRTUFH", "JEURTU", "AITUO", "ERTUJG", 
"HERTYE", "DAIER", "ZERV1", "BERTUI")
data <- structure(list(pos = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c = c("AUSTOP", 
"ATIP;AITUO", "BERTUI", "BHTREAK;PAERJR;KIEYTU", "FRTEU3", "IRTUFH", 
"HAZEB", "ERTUJG;JIRTUE;HERTYE", "DAIER1", "ZERV")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but I need an exact match. I edited my previous post to show an example that is not working -> on the line 9: DAIER is detected as a match on DAIER1

Comment: @PatrickParts i changed to add word bounddary

Comment: @PatrickParts please check the update.  I added `BERTUI` in your 'xa' vector

Comment: Thank you, this is now working as I want. I will test on my data and try to understand how these functions work.

Comment: I come back to you, because I found a case where your solution is not working and I would like to know how to considere this case to get what I want. This is not working when string in the column c contains a "-". For example if I have "TEA-1" in the column c and "TEA" in the xa vector, it will detect it as an exact match, but for me this is not. How can I adapt this code in order that the "-" is not considered as a word boundary ?

Comment: @PatrickParts try with `data %>% mutate(new = map_chr(strsplit(c, ";"), ~ str_c(intersect(., xa), collapse = ";")))`

Comment: thank you, this has solved my problems. I am sorry, I have one more related question. I am now trying to adapt this to the function map2_chr in order to keep the strings present in two vector (xa and xb), but my differents tests failed. my last one test: `data %>% mutate(new = map2_chr(strsplit(c, ";"), ~ str_c(intersect(., xa), collapse = ";"), strsplit(c, ";"), ~ str_c(intersect(., xb), collapse = ";"), ~str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse=";")))`. I got this error message x Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:.

Comment: I guess it is because the second argument of the map2_chr is not what ir should be, but I don't know how to write this in another way.

Comment: @PatrickParts Based on your your code, I think you need to use `map_chr` individually on both and then loop over the output with `map2` or so.  Can you post as a new question to understnad better

Comment: Thank you again for the tip. I did `data %>% 
  mutate(new_1 = map_chr(str_split(c, ";"), ~paste(intersect(.x, xa), collapse = ";")), new_2 = map_chr(str_split(c, ";"), ~paste(intersect(.x, xb), collapse = ";"))) %>% mutate(new_3 = map2_chr(new_1, new_2, ~ str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse=";")))` and so far,  it seems to works.